# How do I ask someone to limit the scope of their questions?

Tags: questions, formality

I am required to represent my university with an introductory speech to our Japanese Exchange students. I would like to express at one point that my Japanese, though I may appear to speak it well in this speech, is limited, and as such could they please limit their questions to * examples of questions relevant to their tour *

Any assistance anyone could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about your university, so does "tour" mean some introductory tour or their exchange period or something else?

Comment: @broccoliforest tour is an introductory tour of our facilities. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

"Could you please limit (the scope of) your questions to * examples of questions relevant to their tour *?"

How about...

> - ご質問は、(examples of questions) (など)といったものに｛[限]{かぎ}らせて / [限定]{げんてい}させて｝｛いただきます / いただきたいと思います｝。
> - ご質問は、(examples of questions) (など)といったものの｛[範囲]{はんい}で / [範囲内]{はんいない}で｝｛お願いします / お願いいたします｝。
> - (examples of questions) といったご質問のみ[受付]{うけつ}けさせて｛いただきます/ いただきたいと思います｝。

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would say in Japanese.

[私]{watashi} [は]{wa} [日本語]{nihongo} [は]{wa}[あまり]{amari}[話せない]{hanasenai}[の]{no}[で]{de}、[質問]{shitumon}[に]{ni}[は]{wa}[うまく]{umaku}[答えられない]{kotaerarenai}[かもしれません]{kamoshiremasen}。

= My Japanese is limited so I'm afraid I won't be able to answer your questions.

Comment: Rie, there's a helpful ruby tool on the SE where you can type a word in [] followed by the reading in {}. This will make a prettier version of what  you did for the answer.